# How to find and delete unmatched records from database using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

In my database, I have an upload table and an employee table. There is an Employee class file and an Upload Item class file in the model class. I need to edit employee information. There are 2 upload files for employee id number 1. In the edit action, the user deleted one file (Id no:2 image was deleted). The model is passed to the back end. The back end gets the model and needs to validate the uploaded files. Upload table has two records for employee id 1. Front-end code sends file  request. In that case, At that point, I need to check which file from the table does not match. If an unmatched record is found, I need to delete it. As an example, I need to remove the record id number 2 from upload table. Below I explain my code.

Upload Table :

| Id | File Name | URL | EmployeeId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | home.jpg | C:\home.jpg | 1 |
| 2 | flower.jpg | C:\flower.jpg | 1 |

Upload Item Model Class:

```
public class UploadItem()
{
    [Key]
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string FileName {get;set;}
    public string URL {get;set;}
    public int EmployeeId {get;set;}
}
```

Employee Table :

| Id | Employee Name | PhoneNo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Joseph | 89772 |
| 2 | rosy | 3244 |

Employee Model class:

```
public class Employee()
{
    [Key]
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string EmployeeName {get;set;} 
    public int PhoneNo{get;set;}
    public List<IFormFile> files {get;set;}
    public List<UploadItem> uploadfiles {get;set;}
}
```

Controller class:
//Method Summary : Need to removed unmatched records from upload tables.

```
[HTTPPOST("EditEmployee")]

public async Task<IActionResult> EditEmployee([FormFrom] Employee model)
{
    if(model.uploadfiles.Count>0)
    {
       var uploadRecordsFromDB= dbContext.Uploads.Where(x=>x.EmployeeId==model.Id).ToList();
       var uploadRecordsFromRequest=model.uploadfiles;
    //Finding unmatched records method1:
       var unMatchedRecords = uploadRecordsFromDb.Where(x=> !uploadRecordsFromRequest.Contains(x)).ToList(); 
    //Finding unmatched recordss method 2:
       var unMatchedRecords1= uploadRecordsFromDB.Where(i => !uploadRecordsFromRequest.Contains(i)).ToList();
    
    }
}
```

The result I expect is

| Id | File Name | URL | EmployeeId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | home.jpg | C:\home.jpg | 1 |

Comment: Specify the exact ORM version you are using.

Comment: Entity Framework Core (Back end API Asp.net Core)

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer:

//Unmatched records found using the linq query:

```
 [HTTPPOST("EditEmployee")]
    
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditEmployee([FormFrom] Employee model)
    {
        if(model.uploadfiles.Count>0)
        {
           
           var uploadRecordsFromDB= dbContext.Uploads.Where(x=>x.EmployeeId==model.Id).ToList();
    var uploadRecordsFromRequestIds=model.uploadfiles.Select(x=>x.Id).ToList();
    var unmatchrecords = (from file in uploadRecordsFromDB 
                                           where !uploadRecordsFromRequestIds.Contains(file.Id) select file).ToList();
        foreach (var unmatchrecord in unmatchrecords) 
                    {
                        dbContext.Uploads.Remove(unmatchrecord);
                        dbContext.SaveChanges();
                    }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Alexander Petrov I updated the deletion code

Comment: It is much better  for many reasons to use dbContext.Uploads.RemoveRange(unmatchrecords);